# Im confused on how can I manipulate the properties inside an instance when it gets deinitialized?

Tags: ios, swift, instance, dealloc, deinit

I have this from either the Apple documentation or the swift book

> When an instance gets deinitialized, you still have access to the
>   properties inside the instance and can manipulate them as needed
>   before the instance totally goes away.

I'm confused, do they mean when we for example do some mathematical action using the instances property in the `deinit()` method? or lets say when we print a property of type `string` that was part of a specific instance, also from the `deinit`() method?
If so, then is the `deinit()` method the only way to manipulate a property when it is being deinitialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the `deinit` method gets called *just before* the instance gets deinitialized, to give you a final opportuninty to do whatever you need to do (cleanup, close a file, terminate a network connection, etc).

What the documentation says is that, at the time `deinit` is called your object has not been deinitialized yet (but will be very soon), so you still can (for the last time) access its properties.

Comment: I wouldn't terminate network connections there... i'd have a dedicated close() or stop() method as there is no guarantee WHEN deist is called. ONLY that it is called before deallocation [whenever that is]

Comment: It was just an example of something you might need to do just before the object gets deallocated. Any kind of cleanup would do.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a swift class with a a var you know you have to clean up after because ARC can't free it (e.g. C memory), you can still do that in deinit. The pointers stored in the properties are still valid!

it isn't useful for much more though (ok end observing with the notification center or kvo) BECAUSE there is no guarantee WHEN deist is called. ONLY that it is called before deallocation [whenever that is]

Answer (score 2):

`deinit` is called right before deallocation (when the retainCount reaches 0), so all your properties are still valid and you can print your string. You don't need to set properties to nil explicitly in `deinit` as that happens automatically.

This being said, most classes don't even need `deinit` implemented

Most of the time I used `deinit` to remove observer that the instance is registered to, post any notifications if needed, and things like that.